# Bash - Test for multiple users

Tags: bash

I am trying to test if current user one of two allowed users to start a process, but I can't seem to get the multi-condition to work correctly:

```
test ($(whoami) != 'mpurcell' || $(whoami) != 'root')) && (echo "Cannot start script as non-ccast user..."; exit 1)
```

Is there a way to test multiple users without have to enter two lines, like this:

```
test $(whoami) != 'mpurcell' && (echo "Cannot start script as non-ccast user..."; exit 1)
test $(whoami) != 'root' && (echo "Cannot start script as non-ccast user..."; exit 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bash 3.x and above have a regular expression match operator `=~` available in the [[ operator

```
if [[ ! "$(whoami)" =~ ^(mpurcell|root)$ ]]
then
    echo "Go away" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

etc...

I was reading that quoting rules on the regular expression changed in bash 3.2 or so. The above works on my 3.2.25, you may need to quote it if your bash is older.

Comment: You should use `^(mpurcell|root)$` to avoid matching e.g. jethrootis.  Also, you can do the negation with `[[ ! "$(whoami)" =~ ^(mpurcell|root)$ ]]`

Answer (score 2):

`test` is just a command, so its expression is parsed just like the arguments to any other command -- meaning that parentheses, pipes, etc must be escaped or quoted to work (and to avoid trouble with this, `test` uses `-o` instead of `||`).  If you're actually using bash, it has a `[[ ]]` test expression that avoids these parsing oddities.

Also, your expression logic is off.  You report the error if the current user isn't mpurcell *or* isn't root; since the current user can't be both, it'll always error out.  I'm pretty sure you want an *and* there.

Finally, since you have the `echo ...; exit 1` part in parentheses, it'll be executed in a subshell, and hence the `exit` command will exit the subshell, not the script.  To avoid this, use `{ ... }` instead of parentheses.

Here's a bash version:

```
[[ $(whoami) != 'mpurcell' && $(whoami) != 'root' ]] && { echo "Cannot start script as non-ccast user..."; exit 1; }
```

And here's a version that should work in a generic POSIX shell:

```
test "$(whoami)" != 'mpurcell' -a "$(whoami)" \!= 'root' && { echo "Cannot start script as non-ccast user..."; exit 1; }
```

Comment: +1 for clarification, I opted to go with Rich's solution only because I have to call `whoami` once.

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
**[ $(whoami) != 'mpurcell' -a $(whoami) != 'root' ] && (echo "Cannot start script as non-ccast user..."; exit 1)**

Comment: Thanks for the response, I opted to go with Rich's response.